# Calculate limit in limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\lim_{k \to \infty}(\cos{(|n!\pi x|)^{2k}} )) $

Tags: calculus, limits

I have problem with calculating $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}(\lim_{k \to \infty}(\cos{(|n!\pi x|)^{2k}}  )) $

I only get hint that it will be $1 \vee 0$ regarding to wheter $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $x \in (\mathbb{R}- \mathbb{Q})$ but don't have idea how to find it.

Comment: Intuitively, which do you think is zero and which $1$?

Comment: Intuitevely $1$ for rational, but these two limits means the same as one limit with double index $n,k$  meaning $\displaystyle \lim_{n,k \to \infty}$ ??

Comment: Note that if $x$ is a rational number, then $n!x$ is an integer (in fact, an *even* integer) for all sufficiently large integral $n$. And if $x$ is not rational, then $n!x$ is not an integer for any positive integral $n$.

Comment: It is not a single limit. You must first take one limit, then the other (a so-called "iterated" limit). Order is important here.

Comment: If $x$ is rational then for large enough $n$ we have $n!x$ is an integer, so the limit is $1$. For fixed $n$, if $x$ is irrational, $(\cos(n!\pi x))^{2k}$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$.